# storm—clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException

Tags: clojure, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I encounterd this problem in my first storm&kafka examples.It seems that it's because of the clojure-1.4.0.jar's missing.But I have added it to the build path of the project.

```
9649 [main] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at storm.topology.MyKafkaTopology.main(MyKafkaTopology.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/esotericsoftware/kryo/io/Input, compiling:(backtype/storm/daemon/executor.clj:481)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6462) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6262) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6443) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6262) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6223) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$IfExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:2642) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6455) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6262) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$100(Compiler.java:37) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5883) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6455) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6262) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6443) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6262) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6223) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5618) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5054) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3674) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6453) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6262) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6443) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6262) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$100(Compiler.java:37) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5883) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6455) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6262) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6443) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6262) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6223) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5618) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5919) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a dependency. Try adding this to `storm/topology/MyKafkaTopology` -

```
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input;
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.But it didn't work.I have solved the problem just now.It's becase I use maven to help me manage the project,and when I use maven to help me download the dependency of storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar.It didn't work right.                                                                        I delete the dependency of storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar in the pom.xml,And add all the jars in the resource of storm-0.9.1-incubating's lib.Then the project works well.Thank you once more for answering my question.